# How to paint a color with alpha over an image - C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

What I'm trying to do is paint a solid color and/or pattern with some degree of opacity over an existing image. I believe from what I've read this will involve a bitmap mask.  The examples I've seen using bitmap masks as opacity masks only show them used against images to crop them a certain way, and I want to use it for painting.  Here is basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: 1. image, 2. mask, 3. result]

The first image is being loaded and drawn onto a derived Canvas class using DrawImage.  I'm trying to accomplish what you see in the 3rd image, the 2nd is an example of a mask I might use.  The two key points being that the blue surface in the 3rd image needs to be any arbitrary color, and it needs some opacity so that you can still see the shading on the underlying image.  This is kind of a simple example, some of the other objects have much more surface detail and much more complicated masks.

Comment: are you working on a dentistry app? that's awesome!

Comment: It isn't clear at all why you want to use a mask.  Just use Graphics.FillRectangle(), using a SolidBrush that you created with a Color whose alpha is less than 255.

Comment: A good study for this kind of thing is the last open-source version of Paint.NET - https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/source/checkout

Comment: @HansPassant the mask doesn't seem to be a rectangle - it seems he wants to be able to contrast an arbitrary region.

Comment: Well, then Graphics.FillPath() or FillRegion() ought to fit the bill.

Comment: If you are using yourself in the example, you have very good brushing habits.

Comment: @HansPassant A rectangle or FillPath won't work - as I said this is a simple example, but some of the masks are very complex, and it would be unfeasible to translate them to paths.  We have over 1500 regions that we need to highlight with arbitrary colors.  The above is probably the simplest example.

Comment: @amnesia do you know the `Marker` brush used in `Paint` in `Windows 7 or above`? Isn't that `partial transparency` what you want? You just gave out a simple example and want to get some very detailed/complicated/concrete solution? All I understand is you want to paint some simple shape over the existing bitmap with arbitrary color and transparency. If it's just that, using `Color.FromArgb()` to get the correct color to paint/fill your shape should help.

Comment: @KingKing Although the example I gave is mostly rectangular, as I mentioned in my other comments we have a large number of different regions that are arbitrary shapes outlining anatomical surfaces, and mapping them to vector paths is not feasible.  We have to be able to do this using bitmap masks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A color matrix can be useful here:

```
private Image tooth = Image.FromFile(@"c:\...\tooth.png");
private Image maskBMP = Image.FromFile(@"c:\...\toothMask.png");

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  base.OnPaint(e);

  e.Graphics.DrawImage(tooth, Point.Empty);

  using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(maskBMP.Width, maskBMP.Height, 
                                 PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)) {

    // Transfer the mask
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
      g.DrawImage(maskBMP, Point.Empty);
    }

    Color color = Color.SteelBlue;
    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix(
      new float[][] {
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0.5f, 0},
        new float[] { color.R / 255.0f,
                      color.G / 255.0f,
                      color.B / 255.0f,
                      0, 1}
      });

    ImageAttributes imageAttr = new ImageAttributes();
    imageAttr.SetColorMatrix(matrix);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,
                         new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size),
                         0,
                         0,
                         bmp.Width,
                         bmp.Height,
                         GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr);
  }
}
```

The 0.5f value in the Matrix declaration is the alpha value.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much for the info! I'm trying to adapt it to work within the OnRender function of a WPF Canvas class, which gets passed a DrawingContext instead of PaintEventArgs, and the DrawingContext.DrawImage function does not have a version that accepts ImageAttributes.  Do you know how I could obtain the appropriate function from a DrawingContext?

Comment: @amnesia Missed the part where this was WPF.  See [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).  I can't offer much more than that — my background is in WinForms.

Comment: My fault for leaving that out.  I really appreciate your stellar efforts here, you've definitely got me going in the right direction.

Comment: We ended up just porting the control to WinForms and using a WindowsFormsHost in our WPF project.  Just wanted to say thanks again, you saved me a lot of time.